# Temporary highlighting of regexp

Tags: highlighting

In `Emacs 26` I had this working macro:

```el
(defmacro with-temp-highlights (&rest body)
  "It executes BODY, undoing, upon completion, all the highlighters
used, but leaving pre-existing highlighters unchanged."
  (declare (indent 0))
  `(unwind-protect
       (let ((font-lock-keywords font-lock-keywords)
             (hi-lock-interactive-patterns hi-lock-interactive-patterns))
         ,@body)

     ;; *DUMMY HIGHLIGHT*
     ;; I need it to re-apply the highlights stored in the
     ;; `font-lock-keywords` and `hi-lock-interactive-patterns`
     ;; variables
     (highlight-regexp "MY DUMMY REGEXP")
     (unhighlight-regexp "MY DUMMY REGEXP")))

(defun test-temp-highlights ()
  (interactive)
  (with-temp-highlights 
    (highlight-regexp "foo")
    (read-string "[ENTER]: ")))
```

I used it to highlight "temporarily" some regexp without the need to use `unhighlight-regexp` to restore the buffer highlighting state.

Now I switched to `Emacs 29.1` and the macro does not work appropriately. The first time I use the macro, the regexp/match is first highlighted and then unhighlighted, but from the next time I use it, the match is not highlighted at all.

`hi-lock-mode` is enabled.

Could this be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my macro:

```el
(defmacro with-temp-highlights (&rest body)
  "Ambito: HIGHLIGHTS
Descrizione: Esegue BODY annullando, al termine dell'esecuzione, tutti gli evidenziatori utilizzati, ma mantenendo inalterati gli evidenziatori preesistenti."
  (declare (indent 0))
  `(unwind-protect
       (let ((font-lock-keywords font-lock-keywords)
         (hi-lock-interactive-patterns hi-lock-interactive-patterns)
         (hi-lock-interactive-lighters hi-lock-interactive-lighters))
     ,@body
     )

     (font-lock-flush)))
```

I added a let-binding for the `hi-lock-interactive-lighters` variable.

It seems working fine.